# How to search a subString from a NSString with case-insensitive

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I knew a instance method of NSString.

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

My source string looks like this: "abcdEFGhi"

When I use `[srcStr.rangeOfString:@"efg"];`, there is no substring was found.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is one more version of `rangeOfString` method you could use that.

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
```

So use as below

```
[srcStr rangeOfString:@"efg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for:

```
[srcStr rangeOfString:@"efg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```