# Count number of zero(0) using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, math

I want to count how many number of zero(0) before numeric number. Because I need to save those number which is present before numeric.

Exam:- suppose I have a number 0000102. So I want to calculate how many zero(0) before numeric start. In this exam we are see here is 4 zero's(0) are present. It is possible to calculate this?

Comment: how are you getting this number from?

Comment: From textfield. So number always dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
NSString *strr = @"0000102";
unichar findC;
for (int i = 0; i<strr.length; i++)
 {
    findC = [strr characterAtIndex:i];
     if (findC == '0')
          {
           count++;
          }
     else
           break;
  }
 NSLog(@"%d",count);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sangram, But if string is like "00010002005", that time maybe out is 7's zero(0). right? So, i think it's a wrong arrroach. Remind me string is dynamic. please clarify.

Comment: NO check solution once again it will give you 3

Comment: Yes @sarang, you are right. not count all zero(0). thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0;i<string.length;i++) 
 {  
   if ([[string characterAtIndex:i] intValue] <= 9 || [[string characterAtIndex:i] intValue] > 0 )
     {
       i++;
     }
    else
     {
      numerOfZeros++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach for a one liner:

```
@implementation NSString (category)

- (NSUInteger)zeroPrefixCount
{
    return [string hasPrefix:@"0"] ? 1 + [[string substringFromIndex:1] zeroPrefixCount] : 0;
}

@end
```

This is not an optimal solution, performance-wise, but it's typical of your first days at programming classes.

#### usage

```
// x will be 4
NSUInteger x = [@"0000102" zeroPrefixCount];
```

Comment: Hi @Cœur, this approach is quite right. But if user put 0023405, then I think you code's output will be wrong

Comment: @SanjibDe why? No, output will be correct, it will return 2. Try it.

Comment: @ Cœur, I am so sorry, yes you are also right. Thanks for replying me

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to save this kind of numbers as String itself and no need to further evaluate how many zeros are there rather do a string comparison if needed.

If you really want to count zeros in your number then you can consider converting it to a string and use NSRange and NSString helper methods to get what you want. Similar situation is answered here.

[search if NSString contains value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969147/search-if-nsstring-contains-value)